# Syntax to access rootScope variable in MyController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function MyController() {
                    this.Name = "jag";
                    this.sal = "4500";
                } 

                MyController.prototype.getAnnualSal = function(){
                        return (this.sal) * 12;
                }
                var app = angular.module("sample", []).run(function($rootScope) {
                                                                $rootScope.variable = 1;
                                                            });
                app.controller("emp", MyController);

            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="sample">
            <div ng-controller="emp as o" >
                Hello {{o.Name}}, your annual salary is {{o.getAnnualSal()}}

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Using `run` syntax, `$rootScope.variable` is introduced at module(`sample`) level.

What is the syntax to access `$rootScope.variable` in `MyController?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject rootScope in controller like this.

```
 angular.module('sample', []).controller('emp', function($scope, $rootScope) {

 };
```

> Aside from your issue I dont know why you are mixing controller code in view.Angular is built on MVVM pattern.So separation of controller and view is recommended.

Comment: **One supple:** In my code, What is the advantage of creating `Name` and `sal` as member of controller instance(`o`) rather than members of `$scope`? FYI.. I know that controller instance is a member of `$scope`. One reference-http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Comment: So, Cant't we take similar approach, without injecting `$rootScope` in controller? Otherwise, I did know the syntax that you wrote in the answer

Comment: @overexchange :what are you doing with rootScope? `$rootScope` shouldn't be used to share variables when we have things like services and factories.However you can use `.scope().$root` also to indirectly get hold of rootscope;

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, inject $rootScope into the controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function MyController($rootScope) {
                this.Name = "jag";
                this.sal = "4500";
            } 

            MyController.prototype.getAnnualSal = function(){
                    return (this.sal) * 12;
            }
            var app = angular.module("sample", []).run(function($rootScope) {
                                                            $rootScope.variable = 1;
                                                        });

            MyController.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
            app.controller("emp", MyController);

</script>
```